# Getting incorrect syntax for SQL statement in python

Tags: python, sql-server

When I run below code which incorporates `TOP ?` in a `select` statement and I am unable to resolve.

Code:

```
cnt = self.getCount()
#cnt = 2
query = "select distinct top ? id, indicator from [TABLE] ORDER BY id ASC"
connsql = self.sql_connection()
resultset = connsql.cursor().execute(query, cnt).fetchall()
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

I get this syntax error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: SQL Server does accept [a variable as the `TOP` quantity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so you should be able to pass it as an argument. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: You just need to wrap your ? with parenthesis. distinct top (?)

Comment: @Alex Thank you.Got it.